# How to use disabled CSS pseudo-class to style element with aria-disabled attributes?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I am creating a button component using `aria-disabled` for managing disabled state instead of `disabled` attribute to accommodate accessibility requirements.

Earlier I used CSS pseudo-class [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) to style the disabled component. Is there a way to use it with `aria-disabled="true"` to style the button and `aria-*` attributes in general?

Comment: The real question here is why you have switched to `aria-disabled` rather than `disabled`? Is there something in particular that made you do that?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I am building a date-picker where navigation is handled using keyboard arrow keys. Now if one of the day is disabled (weekends, for example), then it still needs it to be focus-able with keyboard but disabled attribute make it completely non-focus-able. Also, some screen readers are not so gentle with `disabled` attribute. The screen reader should announce that this day exists on picker but not you cannot do anything with it.

Comment: That is fair enough, perfect use case, just normally it is a "code smell" of something being more complicated than it needs to be so thought I would check 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just apply an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) instead of `:disabled`:

```css
[aria-disabled="true"] { /* your declarations */ }
```

Comment: I was more looking for some sort of pseudo selector instead of attribute selector. But, it looks like that's the only way.